# Custom workaround udev script for hibernate/suspend error doesn't work

Tags: sound, suspend, hibernate, udev

So I have an old ASUS K46CM laptop running **Xubuntu 20.04**, with a functioning speaker but defunct audio jack. I've disabled the audio from BIOS now to deal with it.

This presents a new problem: I can no longer hibernate nor suspend this laptop. It generated an error that said:

```
0000:01:00.1: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
```

I googled around and found someone with a seemingly similar problem and a working solution: disable the device on boot with a custom udev rule, from this link below:

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/kernel-5-6-system-freeze-when-resuming-from-suspend-or-hibernate/121630/21

The udev rule in question:

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/10-remove-nvidia-audio.rules
ACTION==“add”, KERNEL==“0000:01:00.1”, SUBSYSTEM==“pci”, RUN+="/bin/sh -c ‘echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.1/remove’"
```

Except that it didn't work for me.

The problematic device:

```
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev ff)
```

... is still listed in my lspci output after I put that workaround:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev ff)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)
```

Perhaps I've missed something? To be honest this is my first time dealing with a problem involving udev rules.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You probably have to change that rule, since the person who wrote that rule has a different sys layout than you. So what happens if you type in a terminal:
`cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.1/remove`, it probably won't exist. So you need to search for the right slot.

Comment: @kanehekili

It's there, but restricted.
    sudo cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.1/remove
    cat: '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.1/remove': Permission denied

Also the permission table:
    --w--w---- 1 root root  4096 Nov  4 10:42 remove

Comment: But it works when I go straight to su and perform the echo command there.

After that, lspci no longer list the problematic device. But I need to do this on boot for the change to persists, and I don't know how yet

Comment: Check with `udevadm info -a /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.1` if you want to test targeting it by other attributes than address. Some rules to be effective on boot need to update ramfs after changes in rules using: `sudo update-initramfs -u`